# wait($time >1000); cannot work in system-verilog?

Tags: system-verilog

I use this code to wait for a specific simulation time

```
initial begin
    $display("A");
    wait($time>1000);
    $display("B");
end
```

the simulation result is:

```
A
```

I didnot see `B` printed.

If I use following code, it works.

```
while($time <1000) #1;
```

Is it because vcs needs to judge the wait condition once any viriable in the condition statement changes, $time is changing too frequently so vcs doesnot allow this usage?

@Tudor 's answer enlighten me. I tried @Tudor 's code with some modification. It turns out when `wait(func(arglist));` vcs only retry to evaluate the function when arglist changes. Because $time has no args, vcs will only evaluate $time the 1st time, won't retry.

```
module top;
  int the_time = 0;
  int  in_arg = 0;

  function int the_time_f(int in);
    return the_time;
  endfunction // the_time_f

  initial begin
    $display("A");

// This works because 'the_time' is a variable
//wait(the_time > 10);

// This doesn't work because 'the_time_f' is a function


wait(the_time_f(in_arg) >10);
    $display("B at %t", $time);
      end

  initial begin
    #10ns;
    the_time = 11;
    #10ns;
    in_arg = 1;
    #20ns;
    $finish();
  end
endmodule // top
```

got following result

```
A
B at 20ns
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a gray area in the standard. In section **9.4 Procedural timing controls** of the [IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) Standard, it's mentioned that event control can be either implicit (changed of nets or variables) or explicit (fields of type `event`). `$time` is a system function, not a variable. I've also tried using a function for the `wait` and it also doesn't work:

```
module top;
  int the_time = 0;

  function int the_time_f();
    return the_time;
  endfunction // the_time_f

  initial begin
    $display("A");

    // This works because 'the_time' is a variable
    //wait(the_time > 10);

    // This doesn't work because 'the_time_f' is a function
    wait(the_time_f() > 10);
    $display("B");
  end

  initial begin
    #10ns;
    the_time = 11;
    #20ns;
    $finish();
  end
endmodule // top
```

Waiting on a change of a variable works fine, but waiting for a change on a function's return value doesn't work. IMHO, the compiler should have flagged this as a compile error (same for using `$time`) since it seems to just ignore the statement.

Answer (score 4):

In an event control `@(expression)` or `wait(expression)` that suspends a process, SystemVerilog scheduling semantics requires an event to evaluate the expression (called an evaluation event. See section *4.3 Event Simulation* of the [1800-2012 LRM](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf)) If an expression includes a function, only the arguments to that function are visible to cause an event evaluation (There is an exception for class methods in at a write to any member of the object in the method call will cause an event) See section *9.4.2 Event control*

In an event driven simulation, the value of **time** is just an attribute of the current time slot, it is never an event. The simulator processes all events for the current time slot in a queue, and when that queue is empty, it advances time to the next time slot queue. So it might simulate time slots 0,5,7,10, skipping over the unmentioned times. Using your `while` loop, that would create a time sot for every consecutive time unit between 0 and 1000 - extremely inefficient.

So just use

```
#(1000); // wait for 1000 relative time units
```

Comment: I use if(time_to_wait>$time) #(time_to_wait - $time);  now to replace the ineffecient while loop. :)

Comment: Is there a way to wait until when the simulation hits a given time, something like `@($time==18.5us)` ?

Comment: @Nazar You can do `#(18.5us-$realtime)`   Using $realtime instead of $time gives you fractional time units if needed.